# Perfoce(P4) constantly fails on a specific file when trying to submit with error: WSAECONNABORTED

Tags: tcp, perforce

I'm not entirely sure what is going on here but perfoce will fail 100% of the time when trying to submit a very specific file in our depot.  Things I have tried to solve this problem:

- It Submit the file on it's own or in a changelist with other files
- Submit using parallel sync or without it
- Adjust the batch and thread numbers
- Submitting via the command line and the visual client
- Increasing or turning off net.maxwait
- Increasing or turning off netkeepalive.idle as well as interval.
- Checking disk space on server( 150GB free)
- Deleting the current instance of the file and copying a backup overtop of the current one

The error message I receive are:

From Client side CLI:

> write: socket: WSAECONNABORTED

From Server logs:

> TCP send failed. write: socket: WSAECONNABORTED Perforce client error:
>           TCP send failed.
>           write: socket: WSAECONNABORTED

Perforce is just flat out refusing to let me submit this one particular file, it's a 63MB file, larger than some but smaller than others which have gone through successfully.  We are on a 30Mbps connection, so I usually get the failure message after 10-20 seconds.  I'm at a loss here so any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What's the name of the file and what's the server OS?

Comment: Do you have a server administrator? Or is this a server that you run yourself? If you have an admin, have they consulted the server logs? If you are running the server yourself, what do its logs say?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the network environment? Are you in a satellite office connecting to the main office over a WAN link? Are you at home, going through an ISP to a public server? Is there something about the name or contents of this file that would cause your ISP to block it?

Comment: File is called: Municipal_Veil.uasset , server is running Ubuntu14.04

I am the server admin yes, I pasted the relevant server log entry in the OP above.

The server is in AZ, our office is in Montreal, QC Canada, about 4000km away. We are connected via a business line.  I can't imagine there's anything about the name of the file that would get it blocked.  The weirdest thing is that we have a mirror depot with this problematic file on it on the same server, no problem submitting it to that depot, but this new instance just won't take it

Comment: @BryanPendleton - The server logs didn't say anything useful unfortunately.

Comment: @DrewMarold - We are in  satellite office connecting to our servers via our ISP.  I suppose the ISP could have been blocking it but that seems odd.  Next time I will try using a VPN to connect and see if that helps